# SQL - return rows with a duplicate value, where one row in each group has a certain attribute and not another

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am a SQL novice at best - appreciate any help on this answer. It's specific to the program MediaMonkey, but more broadly applicable I think since MediaMonkey's database is I believe SQLite 3. The table I'm querying is called Songs and all the columns I'm referencing are in this table.

I am using the Custom4 field in MediaMonkey to store a song's Work ID from Musicbrainz, and the Custom5 field to store the AcoustID. I'm trying to create a playlist of cover / alternate / live versions of songs that I've rated 5 stars, but where the 5 star song is not a classical work or a jazz recording (I use the Grouping field (GroupDesc) to indicate if a track is classical or jazz).

Parameters for the SQL query need to be something like this:

- Same Work ID as a 5 star recording (Rating = 100), where the Grouping
  of the 5 star recording is not 'Classical' or 'Jazz' (I am OK with
  classical or jazz covers of 5 star popular works)
- Different AcoustID from any 5 star recording (eliminate duplicate
  recordings)
- Rating < 5 stars (I don't want to include the 5 star songs
  themselves)

I cobbled together the following SQL query from some examples I found:

```
Songs.Custom4 IN (SELECT Custom4 FROM Songs GROUP BY Custom4 HAVING Count(*) > 1 AND Max(Rating) > 99 AND Custom4 <> '' AND GroupDesc <> 'Classical' AND GroupDesc <> 'Jazz')
```

What this appears to include is the following:

- Same WorkID as a 5 star recording
- Classical or jazz tracks only if the classical or jazz track is rated
  5 stars and there is another track with the same Work ID that is not
  classical or jazz, or if the classical or jazz track has the same
  Work ID as a 5 star recording that is not classical or jazz
- Includes duplicates of the 5 star recording, and includes the 5 star
  recordings themselves

Somehow then I need to filter out the 5 star classical or jazz tracks and the tracks that have the same Work IDs as those tracks, and I need to exclude the duplicates and the 5 star recordings.

Let's say you have a table like this:

```html
<table class="blueTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>&nbsp;Song</th>
<th>Grouping</th>
<th>Rating</th>
<th>Work ID</th>
<th>AcoustID</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>A1</td>
<td>Classical&nbsp;</td>
<td>100&nbsp;</td>
<td>a12&nbsp;</td>
<td>b12&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A2</td>
<td>Jazz&nbsp;</td>
<td>100&nbsp;</td>
<td>a21&nbsp;</td>
<td>b21&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A3</td>
<td>&nbsp;NULL</td>
<td>100&nbsp;</td>
<td>a31&nbsp;</td>
<td>b31&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A4</td>
<td>NULL&nbsp;</td>
<td>NULL&nbsp;</td>
<td>a12&nbsp;</td>
<td>b41&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A5</td>
<td>NULL&nbsp;</td>
<td>NULL&nbsp;</td>
<td>a31&nbsp;</td>
<td>b31&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A6</td>
<td>Classical&nbsp;</td>
<td>NULL&nbsp;</td>
<td>a31&nbsp;</td>
<td>b61&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A7</td>
<td>NULL&nbsp;</td>
<td>NULL&nbsp;</td>
<td>a31&nbsp;</td>
<td>b71&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'd want my query to include the following songs: A6, A7

Here's the logic: A1 and A2 would be excluded since they are Classical and Jazz tracks and are not covers of a popular song with a rating of 100. A3 would be excluded since it has a rating of 100. A4 would be excluded since it's a popular cover of a Classical track that is rated 100. A5 would be excluded since it's a duplicate of A3. A6 is included - it's a Classical cover of A3. A7 is included - it's a cover of A3.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: OK, let's say you have a table like this:

Song   Grouping   Rating   Work ID   AcoustID
A1       Classical   100        a12          b12
A2       Jazz          100        a21          b21
A3       NULL        100        a31          b31
A4       NULL        NULL     a12          b41
A5       NULL        NULL     a31          b31
A6       Classical   NULL     a31          b61
A7       NULL        NULL     a31          b71

I'd want my query to include the following songs:

A6, A7

Comment: Ugh, not sure how to format a table in a comment here. Hope the above helps and is readable. If not I can try to post some other way.

Here's the logic:

A1 and A2 would be excluded since they are Classical and Jazz tracks and are not covers of a popular song with a rating of 100.

A3 would be excluded since it has a rating of 100.

A4 would be excluded since it's a popular cover of a Classical track that is rated 100.

A5 would be excluded since it's a duplicate of A3.

A6 is included - it's a Classical cover of A3.

A7 is included - it's a cover of A3.

Comment: To edit the question, click "edit".